# How to deliver button event to install pop-up

Tags: android

I am writing a program that automatically updates using a local APK file without user interaction.

The update was performed using the Android package installer service as follows.

```
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    intent.setDataAndType(apkUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive")
    startActivity(intent)
```

Is it possible to deliver the Update and Done button events in the update confirmation pop-up like below?

[image]
[image]